# How to return all post with meta keys on top of posts without meta keys?

Tags: wordpress

```
                query_posts(array(
                'posts_per_page'=>-1,
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'meta_key' => 'startDate',
                'meta_value' => date('m.d.Y'),
                'meta_compare' => '>=',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => 'ASC'

            ));
```

I Have this custom query, It return posts with meta key values, my question is how can i return the post without meta key values below the post with meta key values?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use query_posts.  Every time you do, a puppy is killed.  Setup a new query object and use that in your loop.

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_key' => 'startDate',
  'meta_value' => date('m.d.Y'),
  'meta_compare' => '>=',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC'  
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); 

    if( some condition to test for meta value ) :
        // your code
    endif;

    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_query();

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); 

    if( some other condition to test for no meta value ) :
        // your code
    endif;

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, however how can i revert to the default WP query if no metakey value is given? the query above is only returning results with metakey value what about post without metakey value found

Comment: would it be possible to run the original query object without the meta_key?  If not, then start a new query object for the second loop.